# Computing the volume inside a surface S, using a seemingly unrelated result,

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

Consider the surface $$S = \{(x,y,z): x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$$.  What is the volume inside S?

This is actually part (b) of the question.  I'm not sure which approach to take.

But part (a) of the question asked to compute the length of C, where C is the graph of the function f(t) = $\frac {e^t + e^{-t}}{2}$ on the interval [0,$2\pi$].  I was able to solve part (a).

For these questions, almost always we need to use the result found in part (a) to answer part (b) ... but there doesn't seem to be a connection between the two parts of this question at all.

Thanks,

Comment: To get $\{$ and $\}$, use `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: Use spherical coordinates for the first. Use the arclength formula for the second.

Comment: ah, thanks, Professor Scott.

Comment: @grdgfgr, yes, I already solved part (a), using the arclength formula.  I will give part(b) another shot, using spherical coordinates.  But my primary question is:  is there a *connection* between the result in part(a) and part(b)?  ... perhaps I'll find out in my computations now... but feel free to comment further, if you wish.  Thanks,

Comment: @grdgfgr, how can I use spherical coordinates, when the surface is not even a sphere?  there is a tricky xy-term to resolve first.  why do you think?  I am completely stuck.  Thanks,

Comment: @grdgfgr,  
if i move the xy-term to the r.h.s., i would now have a sphere of radius (1-xy)^(1/2). I will try triple integration on this sphere (with integrand = 1.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the volume inside the surface $S$.

Find a linear transformation of the space such that the image of the surface $S$ is the sphere centered on the origin with radius equal to $1$. Then use change of variables theorem for integrals.

Giving some more details
$$(x,y,z) \to x^2 + xy +y^2 + z^2$$ is an inner product. Trying to find an orthogonal basis, you'll see that the linear application
$$A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 1 & 0 \\
  -1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$ transforms the set $B= \{(x,y,z): x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\}$ into the set $B^\prime= \{(u,v,w): u^2 + v^2 + w^2 \le 1\}$. $B\prime$ is the 3D unit ball. Then you can use the Substitution for multiple variables
$$\int_{\varphi(U)} f(R) dR=\int_Uf(\varphi(T))\vert \det (D \varphi)(T)\vert dT$$ with $U=B$, $\varphi=A$, $\varphi(U)=B^\prime$ and $f=1$ you get

$$\int_{B^\prime} 1dR=\frac{4}{3}\int_B 1 dT \text{ as } \det A =\frac{4}{3}$$

What you're looking for is $\displaystyle \int_B 1 dT$ which is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}\int_B 1 dR = \frac{3}{4} \frac{4}{3} \pi^3 = \pi^3$ as the volume of a sphere of radius $r$ is equal to $\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$

Comment: Hi @jean-pierreMerx, will the volume of the image of S, under such a linear transformation be preserved, though?  (If I understood your hint correctly, then I will be using triple integration, in spherical coordinates, on the unit sphere.)

Comment: The volume of the image will not be preserved, but will be very easy to compute as it will be the volume of the unit sphere multiplied by a constant.

Comment: Hi @Jean-PierreMerx, I'm still working on it, but more on trying to use brute force integration and not an intermediate linear transformation, which I feel would probably not be instructive, hence I wouldn't remember the technique in the future.  Or, when you say a "linear transformation", do you really mean that I should try to make an intermediate change of variables first?  (and then go to spherical coordinates from there.)

Comment: Or you really mean, "use linear algebra, apply a matrix equation..." for this calculus problem?

Comment: if i move the xy-term to the r.h.s., i would now have a sphere of radius (1-xy)^(1/2).  I will try triple integration on this sphere (with integrand = 1.)

Comment: ...which is problematic, since now the innermost integral has an upper limit that depends on all three variables, r, theta, and phi...

Comment: I gave a more detailed solution.